# Can't find the IP address of the printer

Tags: networking, printing, ethernet

I'm trying to connect a generic thermal printer via ethernet. But I can't seem to find a way to find it's IP address.

```
$ dmesg
[  832.709585] e1000e: enp0s31f6 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
```

```
$ sudo ifconfig

enp0s31f6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::e7b:ce95:c38:5138  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether a4:4c:c8:6b:98:ec  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 177  bytes 32617 (32.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xef200000-ef220000
```

```
$ lpinfo --include-schemes dnssd -v
```

```
$ sudo lpstat -t
scheduler is running
no system default destination
lpstat: No destinations added.
lpstat: No destinations added.
```

```
$ lpinfo -v
file cups-brf:/
network beh
network socket
network lpd
direct hp
network ipps
network ipp
network https
network http
direct hpfax
```

Installation manual suggest that I create 'AppSocket/HP JetDirect' connection in CUPS and to set device URI in the format socket://192.168.1.240:9100

What I see in the `ifconfig` is an inet6 address. But how to find the IP that I could use, when setting up 'AppSocket/HP JetDirect' connection in CUPS?

Comment: none of the commands you use is related to printers. try `lpstat -t`

Comment: @Rinzwind Thanks for the info. I updated the question.

Comment: you still need to install it. cups uses a webpage so open a browser and use http://localhost:631/printers/ as an adress. if cups is up you'll see a page where you can add printers.

Comment: I could access cups. When adding the network printer I need to set the socket URL. The problem is that I can't find the IP address of the printer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure your printer gets a fixed IP address so it doesn't change all the time when the DHCP least time runs out.

If you are in a home network, most home DSL routers (FritzBox etc.) have an option to always assign the same IP to a device, even with DHCP (they basically assign the same IP to the same MAC address). In some cases you can even assign a hostname to the device so you can use the hostname ("photo-printer" or whatever).

The router is also your best bet to identify the printer's IP; go to the "network overview" (or whatever it's called in your router) and check out the device vendor.

If that doesn't work, check if you can make your printer print a status page; or sometimes it's even somewhere in the printer's menu.

Answer (score 0):

execute    `/usr/lib/cups/backend/snmp`.